# SAF - NullPointerException when copying file from private app folder to authorized SAF folder

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, file-copying, android-fileprovider, storage-access-framework

My app has to copy a file from private app folder to a SAF folder with the suitable permissions granted.

The used code is:

```
static boolean copyFileToTargetFolderWithNewName(Activity activity, String docUri,String targetFolderUri,String newName)
{
    deleteIfExisting(activity,Uri.parse(targetFolderUri),newName);

    File newFile = new File(docUri);
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "com.myappname.fileprovider", newFile);

    ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    boolean result=false;

    Log.d("copy",contentUri+" "+targetFolderUri+" "+newName);

    try {
//error here
        Uri newUri=DocumentsContract.copyDocument(resolver,contentUri,Uri.parse(targetFolderUri)); 
        DocumentsContract.renameDocument(resolver,newUri,newName);
        result=true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        result=false;
    }
   return result;
}
```

The log output yields:

D/copy: content://com.myappname.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.myappname.app/files/subfolder/file.txt

content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2FSAFfolder/subfolder

newname.txt

What's wrong?
Is this a flags problem? Are the two domains not compatible for copying?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to copy a non-document `Uri` (`contentUri`), and [the JavaDocs for `copyDocument()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract?hl=en#copyDocument(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri)) state that the first parameter needs to be a document `Uri`:

> document with Document#FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY This value must never be null.

When `DocumentsContract` refers to a `Uri` as a "document", it means a `Uri` obtained through `DocumentsContract` itself. That would include a `Uri` obtained through `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or a `Uri` obtained through a tree `DocumentFile`. However, **that will not cover**:

- A `Uri` created by `Uri.fromFile()`
- **A `Uri` from `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`**
- A `Uri` created by `Uri.parse()` from an `http` or `https` URL
- Etc.

Comment: I think "This value must never be null"  prescription is fulfilled in the method call with all three parameters. But still the NullPointerError is a strange error in this case.

Comment: @P5music: Without a stack trace, I cannot really comment on that. My guess is that `DocumentsContract` assumes the `Uri` is really a document `Uri`, tries making a `query()` using it, and gets back unexpected results in the `Cursor`.