# Android SAF, cannot copy file, FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY not set

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-permissions, intentservice

I'm trying to copy a document with the SAF framework in Android by using [DocumentsContract.copyDocument(ContentResolver, Uri, Uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#copyDocument(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri)) however this doesn't work, android returns error "Failed to copy document".

By narrowing the issue down, the `FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY` is **off** on that document (according to [DocumentsContract.Document#COLUMN_FLAGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.Document#COLUMN_FLAGS))
(COLUMN_FLAGS value is 326 in decimal). So this explains the error.

However moving the document is allowed (flag `FLAG_SUPPORTS_MOVE` is **on**) and file is really moved when calling `DocumentsContract.moveDocument(ContentResolver, Uri, Uri, Uri)`

Access to the document tree (both the root of the drive, and DCIM folder) have been granted through `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

*Why is the `FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY` set to false for the Document ? Am I missing something ?*

Note: I believe I fullfill the requirements from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58147682/15401262

Thank you

**Code (java)**

```
// docFilesToProcess if of type "DocumentFile[]" and contains "regular files, like images" (not directories).
// Create destination dir
Uri destUri = DocumentsContract.createDocument(this.getContentResolver(), docFilesToProcess[i].getParentFile().getUri(), DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR, "destDir");
Log.i("M", "destUri: "+ destUri.toString());
// Create document
Uri docToMove = DocumentsContract.createDocument(this.getContentResolver(), docFilesToProcess[i].getParentFile().getUri(), "text/plain", "text");
Log.i("M", "docToMove: "+ docToMove.toString());
// copy document
DocumentsContract.copyDocument(this.getContentResolver(), docToMove, destUri);
```

**Output**

```
I/M: destUri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADCIM/document/primary%3ADCIM%2FdestDir
I/M: docToMove: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADCIM/document/primary%3ADCIM%2Ftext.txt
W/DocumentsContract: Failed to copy document
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Copy not supported
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:658)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:2042)
        at android.provider.DocumentsContract.copyDocument(DocumentsContract.java:1442)
        at com.example.exifthumbnailadder.MainActivity.addThumbs(MainActivity.java:1036)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

**Persistant permission request**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Copy not supported` I never saw something different from this. Its not implemente yet i think..

Comment: `Persistant permission request` No, no. Remove those flags there. They make no sense at all. You cannot grand anything there. You should be glad that in onActivityResult you are granted access to the obtained ur. In onActivity result you should take persistable uri permissions.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I'm not sure what you mean but I don't do these permission requests at the time I call `copyDocument`. I did in the onActivityResult (with the call to takePersistableUriPermission and others) at the time I picked the dir in the UI. 

For now a `getPersistedUriPermissions()` before the copyDocuments block above return `UriPermission {uri=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADCIM, modeFlags=3,...`. So I guess this is ok.

Comment: You should have persisted permission for both directory and file at the time of copy. And...remove those flags..

Comment: Ok, I removed the flags (had no noticable adverse effect). Then, just before the copyDocument, I added, for both URIs (destUri & docToMove), the `grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), theURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);` & `getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(destUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION );`. They are in the persistPerms. I still have the same error and FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY is off ...

Comment: `Then, just before the copyDocument, I added, for both URIs` Both actions make no sense. For the first: you cannot grand anything and i said that before. For the second: what shall i say. Useless. Persistable uri permissions you should take in onActivityResult as that is the place where permissions are offered to you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. You say I should have persistent permission, so to be sure I have them I do the call again (I already have a grantUri... & takePersistable... in the onActivityResult). I checked with getPersistedUriPermissions() if both directory & file are in the list of persistedUriPerm before I call copyDocument, and they are. Isn't this what you meant ? BTW is that permission problem the cause of the copy not working (while moveDocument works perfectly). Thanks again.

Comment: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Copy not supported` That is all.

Comment: so it means android doesn't support copying on local storage with SAF ? :/

Comment: No. It means that that function cannot be used. Of course you can copy files with SAF. Or with DocumentFile or with DocumentsContract.

Comment: Ok. I don't see a copy method in DocumentFile, How do you suggest to do it ?

Comment: You have to obtain an uri for the destination file using for instance  DocumentsContract.createFile. Further you have an uri for the source file. Using content resolver  open an InputStream an OutputStream and read/write all bytes. Using DocumentFile about the same.

Comment: Ok I will try that. But I guess document attributes (creationTime, modificationTime) will be lost. Why the flag `FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY` is set to false is a mistery. Do you have any explanation for this ? BTW, if we transpose the case to a media file, is there an equivalent to copyDocument for the mediastore that would work ? or is it also necessary to do it with InputStream and OutputStream.

Comment: For the MediaStore i use .insert() to obtain an uri where to write the new file to. About the same then. For the rest i know nothing..

Comment: It works fine with InputStream and OutputStream. Thank you.

Comment: @usilo, I was also fighting with this problem and yet do not able to apply DocumentsContract.copyDocument. As I wrote before, moving, creating, deleting are working fine, but somehow there is an exception for copying. As far as I understood from your messaging here, you are also giving up the idea of using of DocumentsContract.copyDocument.
The interesting thing is that unlike of me (I'm kind a beginner in Android) I noticed that even skilled guys here encounter troubles with "copyDocument - copy not supported" issue.

Comment: There is a ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182942755

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot ever rely on any SAF provider to implement any optional feature. You should check whether the feature is supported, and you should have a viable fallback plan for when it is not.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
if((flags & FLAG_SUPPORTS_MOVE) == FLAG_SUPPORTS_MOVE)
    Uri newDoc = DocumentsContract.copyDocument(cr, docToCopy, destDir);
else {
    Uri newDoc = DocumentsContract.createDocument(cr, destDir, mimeType, name);
    manuallyCopyBytes(docToCopy, newDoc);
}
```

It's important to give the provider a chance to do it, because something like Google Drive may be able to perform the copy separately on the device and on the server, instead of copying it on the device and then having to upload the whole thing to the server again.